# Node.js and mssql connection

Tags: node.js, sql-server, connection, backend

I created this Microsoft SQL Server and a database with two tables in it. I am using Node.js for the backend but I am having trouble making a connection from node.js to mssql. I am using Visual Studio and have all the required frameworks and packages needed. I am not getting any errors but I'm also not getting the output. I want to understand if its connected and I want the code to work. My node.js and SQL are working fine though.

```
    const sql = require('mssql')
    const sqlConfig = {

    server: "10.0.0.102\\MSSQLSERVER",
    port: 1433,
    pool: {
        max: 10,
        min: 0,
        idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
    },
    options: {
    encrypt: true,
    trustServerCertificate: false
    }
}

async () => {
    try {
     // make sure that any items are correctly URL encoded in the connection string
     await sql.connect(sqlConfig)
     const result = await sql.query`select * from multiuserlogin`
     console.dir(result)
    } catch (err) {
     // ... error checks
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you not getting any errors because they're being eaten by the code? i.e.: `catch (err) { }` isn't doing anything to display errors.

Comment: Aside... if you already know what port number an instance is listening on then just specify that to connect directly. When you include an instance name in the `server` property it creates additional network dependencies: it forces the client to use the SQL Server Resolution Protocol to communicate with the SQL Browser service over udp/1434 to resolve the `MSSQLSERVER` instance name to the TCP port number that it's listening on, then the client uses that port number to connect to the instance.

Comment: Aside... `encrypt: true` in conjunction with `trustServerCertificate: false` will likely cause your connection to fail, unless the X.509 certificate presented by the SQL Server instance just happens to be CA-issued, current and have a `Subject: 10.0.0.102` or `DnsName: 10.0.0.102` property.